# How to delete attachment that's blocked?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Our mailboxes (Microsoft Exchange) are limited to 2 GB. I'm almost out of space. I'm trying to make space by deleting large attachments from old emails.

This is easy enough (albeit tedious) except for one email. I can't delete the attachment because Outlook has hidden it (nothing to right-click on):

> Outlook blocked access to the following potentially unsafe attachments `ABC2000.chm`

How can I delete the blocked attachment (without deleting the email)? This seems a design flaw.

Comment: Your IT department can configure the group policy so the file extension isn't blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward the message to yourself and not attach the file.

Here other solutions:
https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/829982

Comment: Thanks. That's ridiculous, but I think it'll work.

Comment: Didn't work. The forwarded email was 12 MB in size too.

Comment: Choosing Reply instead of Forward kept the body but got rid of the attachment.

Comment: Thank you for this Q&A. I had the same ridiculous problem, and this uber-simple solution solved it without needing to make a temporary edit to the registry, as instructed in the linked page (English version: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/outlook-blocked-access-to-the-following-potentially-unsafe-attachments-c5c4a480-041e-2466-667f-e98d389ff822).

Answer (score 2):

It actually sounds like by design, but you can forward the email to yourself without the attachment, then delete the original.

Comment: "We think this file is unsafe so we're going to keep it on your computer forever and not let you delete it."

Comment: No. Emails can be legally binding. Modification to an email could cause issues. You can't delete it separately because of this. You can't open it because of security settings. So, yes by design.